# Why changing the scope of quantity_and_stock_status from Global to Website level does not affect the Quantity and Stock Status field?

Tags: magento2, product, stock, inventory, scope

I have changed the scope of `quantity_and_stock_status` in Stores > Attributes > Product > from `Global` to `Web Site`:
[image]

But while creating new products or editing existing products the `Quantity` and `Stock Status` fields are still at the scope `Global` and changing value for one website affects the other website.

[image]

**Note:** This is a fresh Installation of Magento ver. 2.3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Qty and stock status attribute is a "fake" attribute. It does not keep values. It is just a proxy to the stock data which is kept in a separate table.
But to answer your question, you still see the `[GLOBAL]` tag in the product add / edit form is because this is hardcoded somewhere in the code.
There is this form modifier class `Magento\CatalogInventory\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AdvancedInventory` that changes the way the `quantity_and_stock_status` attribute is displayed in the product form.

Take a look at the `prepareMeta` method in the class.
What this does is to add 2 fields in the form and both of them have `scopdeLabel = '[GLOBAL]'`.

Comment: that answers my question, on a quick note to be specific, does it mean that Magento does not support Quantity and Stock Status management at the web site level by default for the open-source version?

Comment: Not in the way you expect it to. It does have the Multi node inventory module(s) that can be enabled and allow you to manage multiple stocks for a product but they are not necessarily at a website level